# Group by single element, putting in a list some row

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq that create a list of object (9 element right now) such as :

```
Object 1:   Title: Title1
            Value: Marco

Object 2:   Title: Title2
            Value: Paolo

Object 3:   Title: Title3
            Value: Giovanni

Object 4:   Title: Title1
            Value: Edoardo

Object 5:   Title: Title2
            Value: Chris

Object 6:   Title: Title3
            Value: John

Object 7:   Title: Title1
            Value: Manuel

Object 8:   Title: Title2
            Value: Lorenz

Object 9:   Title: Title3
            Value: Ernest
```

Instead of this 9 object, I'd like to return only 3 Object (group by Title), having as Value for each object the union list for each Value on each Grouping. So the result should be somethings like :

```
Object 1:   Title: Title1
            Value[]: Marco, Edoardo, Manuel

Object 2:   Title: Title2
            Value[]: Paolo, Chris, Lorenz

Object 3:   Title: Title3
            Value[]: Giovanni, John, Ernest
```

is it possible on Linq? Or I need to iterate my list and manage it manually?

P.S. Note this is only an example! In my scenario, for each Object I have More element than Title and Value, such as 10 element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = objects.GroupBy(o => o.Title)
                   .Select(g => new  
                   {
                       Title = g.Key,
                       Value = g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()
                   });
```

Or with query syntax:

```
var query = from o in objects
            group o by o.Title into g
            select new 
                   {
                       Title = g.Key,
                       Value = g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()
                   });
```

*UPDATE* Consider using simple grouping - this will return objects grouped by title

```
var query = objects.GroupBy(o => o.Title);
```

Comment: That's a bit redundant when, instead of only title and value, I have 9-10 other elements for each object, because I need to re-define all

Comment: @markzzz sorry, didn't get what you mean? Maybe you need simple grouping or lookup?

Comment: For each object, I don't have only Title and Value! BUt many more element, as Title, Value, Max, Min, Data, Pressure, Image, Content, Description, and so on....

Comment: You want to have one object with arrays for each element, or returning group of objects will be ok?

Comment: Suppose I add (on your code) a new variable inside the object, before the GroupBy (such as Value2). Than, on the select after group by, I need to add that variable again! Do you understand what I mean now?

Comment: @markzzz of course you need, if you do projection. Otherwise return whole objects grouped by title

Comment: Such as Value2 = g.Select(x => x.Value2).First(), for each element that, in fact, I don't need to union with other elements...